# Running document.location.hash = "" as first thing in DOM doesn't clean the URL

Tags: firefox, url, dom, hash

document.location.hash="" sets the hash to # in the URL. But when I run this as the first thing in the DOM it doesn't work in Firefox (at least Firefox 5.0.1). Any ideas?

Try visiting http://www.sebastianrazola.com/test.html#thisshouldberemoved in Firefox and another browser to see what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Hash test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.hash="";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>The hash won't be set to <b>#</b> in Firefox. (At least in Firefox 5.0.1)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675587 to be exact (which I believe you filed).

If you want to work around this for the moment, add `document.body.offsetWidth` to your script before the `location.hash` set.  That will create the scrollable layout object whose non-existence causes the error that prevents the location from changing without the bugfix.

Comment: Thanks. Yep I did file the bug.